# Why this generic code with enums doesn't compile

Tags: scala, enums

```
abstract class C[T] {
  def lee: T
}

class CE[T <: Enumeration](val enum: T) extends C[enum.Value] {
  def lee = enum.values.toList(0)
}
```

The error I receive is: Expression of type CE.this.type##enum#Value doesn't conform to expected type enum.type#Value

I'm working with Scala 2.10.4.
My intention is to write generic code on enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
class CE[T <: Enumeration](val enum: T) extends C[T#Value] {
  def lee = enum.values.toList(0)
}
```

which you can create with:

```
val c = new CE[Days.type](Days)
```